# Dynamically create and download an mp3 in Javascript without Flash

Tags: javascript, html, download

I want to do what Downloadify does in this other question: [How do I dynamically create a document for download in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489528/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-document-for-download-in-javascript)

But I would like to do it without using Flash. How can that be done?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Your title says *without Flash* but your question says *with Flash*. Which is it?

Comment: the original question used flash.  so i would assume he means without.

Comment: I'd say "without", since the linked question shows "with"

Comment: Did I put the title as "with Flash"? I'm sorry, I meant to say "without flash".

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you can do is something like this:

```
function addDownloadLinkTo(elem, base64data) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var text = document.createTextNode('Download');
    link.appendChild(text);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + base64data);
    elem.appendChild(link);
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery,

```
$(elem).append($('<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + base64data + '">Download</a>');
```

where `base64data` can be obtained as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript).

Unfortunately, data URIs do not yet (AFAIK) provide a mechanism to specify the file name; also, might not work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks - that gets me text files easily.
I tried doing cat file.mp3 | pbcopy, pasting that into my base64data generation, but I get an error on the page "unterminated string" probably because the paste contains both ' and " characters.

Comment: I saved foo.mp3 from a text editor and opened in vlc. I got the title of the song, but the file wouldn't play. 0:00 duration

Comment: oh, i thought you were doing it *in* JS. Try `openssl base64 -d -in file.mp3 -out file.base64`

Comment: I will, I just don't have the song data on the website yet. So I tried pasting from the command line. WHen I run your command I get file.base64 with 0 size openssl base64 -d -in SilkRain.mp3 -out file.base64

Comment: Whoops, without the `-d`. That's the other direction. (blush)